# ADB Command to set alarm volume to 0 (completely silent)?

Tags: android, adb, volume

On Android 13 (particularly LineageOS 20), the alarm volume level seems to have been limited to a minimum of 1, which means there is still sound coming out, whereas in older Android versions such as Android 8.1 (LineageOS 15.1), the alarm volume level is allowed to be set to 0.

At first I thought it was just a UI limitation, so I turned to ADB commands.

On the phone running Android 13, I ran the command `adb shell cmd media_session volume --show --stream 4 --set 0`, and an error returned showing `Error: invalid volume index 0 for stream 4 (should be in [1..7])` (note that stream 4 means STREAM_ALARM)

And on the phone running Android 8.1, running `adb shell media volume --show --stream 4 --set 0` sets the alarm volume to 0 as expected.

Are there any ADB commands / root-required solutions that let me set the alarm volume to absolutely 0 on Android 13?

I understand it was probably because people complain about accidentally silencing their alarms and miss important meetings or flights, but I personally have to set the alarm to *completely silent* with vibration in some occasions.

Comment: From Android 13, it is not possible to set the alarm volume to 0 directly. You may try using a third-party alarm app or setting Do Not Disturb mode for the specific time.

Comment: How would "do not disturb" mode help? To my knowledge, it even disables vibration.